# Can't apply a texture image to one face - SOLVED

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have a simple model of a building (see below) which I applied 3 different image textures to 3 separate walls and now wish to apply a new image texture to the front wall HOWEVER even after selecting the front face (in edit mode) and applying the new texture image and using UV editing the new image is being applied to both the front and side.
What do I need to do to apply the image texture to ONLY the front face.
Note my building the side has (part of) the same texture image as the front which I have selected in edit mode.
PS how do I attach my zipped blender file?

[image]

Comment: Hello you can use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share your file, don't forget to pack your images

Comment: @moonboots Thanks just remembered I could upload to MEGAsync and here is the link  -                                                                                                                             https://mega.nz/file/Xkp3zBSS#02nJeNAni1iiV7q08NBWOw12EimJLCWVlip_2OyDsGw

Comment: You didn't pack your image, but anyway from what I see if you select the first material of your list, called "Material.side with sign" and click on the Select button it will select 3 faces, so you haven't assigned a separate material to the front face for the moment

Comment: so did you fix your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Firstly I don't know how to "pack you image" and can only think that it means including the 'location folder heirarchy' location of those files.   I have now also included a link to the original blender file and point out that if I select either the front of the building (which appears to have some 'texture' applied) OR the side where the 'Harbour Air' sign is and delete/remove the material (click on the Unlink data-block) the textures from BOTH faces are removed as if they have become linked     https://mega.nz/file/ewp2FTjI#6HKRIoXGCS_az_yLHKIZ2D6uNKuqfLW7e-U8VPqX6_4

Comment: to pack an image, go into the top header menu > File > External Data > Pack Resources. To assign another material to a face, select that material in your material list, select your face, click on the Assign button

Comment: Hopefully the link below contains the packed blender file.  I have tried every think I can find to 'unjoin' the front and side faces which IMHO is the problem.     The other faces are no problem.  https://mega.nz/file/Ssgw2RAa#-ua2pxmFoVD5TOo8KNpgSFnU6tHB5rmwwRz7ePa1yFA

Comment: @moonboots.  I have solved my problem. I selected the front face and then selected another material in the 'list' and clicked on assign and now those two faces are separate. I have NO idea why the material assigned to the side was also assigned to the front. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To assign another material to a face, select that material in your material list, select your face, click on the *Assign* button:

[image]